# Add element in XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I apologize in advance if I do not speak good English, I am an Italian student.

My problem is:

I want to insert a new `admin` element in a XML file and save the result.

For example I want start with this:

```
<admins> 
  <admin> 
    <mail>admin@admin.it</mail> 
    <password>admin</password> 
    <user>admin</user> 
  </admin> 
</admins>
```

and the output that I want is:

```
<admins> 
  <admin> 
    <mail>admin@admin.it</mail> 
    <password>admin</password> 
    <user>admin</user> 
  </admin> 
  <admin> 
    <mail>master@uni.it</mail> 
    <password>master</password> 
    <user>master</user> 
  </admin> 
</admins>
```

How can I do this?

I have tried various methods but none has given good results.

I tried [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML), for example:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("prova.xml");

my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();

my $new_element= $doc->createElement("element4");
$new_element->appendText('testing');

$root->appendChild($new_element);

print $root->toString(1);
```

I can add an element but only locally, I can not save the new item in the file.

Comment: Could you show us what you have already tried (e.g. using an XML parser like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML))? We're glad to help, but we're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: I tried various methods but no one has given good results... I tried XML::LibXML, for example: use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("prova.xml");
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my $new_element= $doc->createElement("element4");
$new_element->appendText('testing');

$root->appendChild($new_element);

print $root->toString(1);   I can add an element but only locally, I can not save the new item in the file ...

Comment: @user3340877 Please update your question instead of put large piece of code in comment, it is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is with XML::Simple

```
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLin('prova.xml', ForceArray => 1);
my $newAdmin = {mail => ['master@uni.it'], password => ['master'], user => ['master']};
push(@{$xml->{admin}}, $newAdmin);
open(XML, '>prova_new.xml');
binmode(XML, ":utf8");
print XML '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".XMLout($xml, RootName => 'admins');
close XML;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, but your own solution seems to be missing only the output to the file.

This program shows how to add a chunk of XML from a text string, and prints the result to `prova_new.xml`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('prova.xml');

my $admins = $doc->getDocumentElement;

$admins->appendWellBalancedChunk(<<'END');
  <admin> 
    <mail>master@uni.it</mail> 
    <password>master</password> 
    <user>master</user> 
  </admin> 
END

open my $out, '>', 'prova_new.xml' or die $!;

print $out $doc->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<admins> 
  <admin> 
    <mail>admin@admin.it</mail> 
    <password>admin</password> 
    <user>admin</user> 
  </admin> 
  <admin> 
    <mail>master@uni.it</mail> 
    <password>master</password> 
    <user>master</user> 
  </admin> 
</admins>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately has a problem, let me just add a new element but if I try again to add another element, the last element replaces the previously element.

Comment: I can't imagine what you've done. If I duplicate the `appendWellBalancedChunk` call then I get another element added.